# Android Studio 3.0: Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just downloaded Android Studio 3.0 and created my first project.
I'm getting an error.

> Gradle '...' project refresh failed error.
>   !Error:org/gradle/tooling/UnsupportedVersionException

The version of Android studio I have:

> Android Studio 3.0  Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 21, 2017 
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
>   JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Have you upgraded your Gradle to 4.1?

Comment: I have Gradle 4.3. Does Android 3.0 require 4.1 specifically? @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: I think it's 4.1+, so you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

On Android studio Update, just do it. 
**Replace** runProguard with minifyEnabled in your gradle build file.

and add gradle plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: I'm having similar issue but couldn't find **runProguard** or **minifyEnabled** inside my build.gradle file. However under the dependencies section of the build.gradle file i have `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }` Any advice on what can be done to fix this issue?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' 
That number at the end should be your android version

Answer (score 0):

imported external model change like as belove :-

compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
 to
compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')