# Android Studio 3.0 says its incompatible with computer

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 3.0.1 from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). Note that the link does not have a different download link for x86 or x64 computers.

I installed it, and loaded it with my pre-installed SDK. Before I could write anything in the new project, this came up:

[image]

As you can see, it is showing that the application is not compatible with the computer.

Any idea what can be done in such a case?

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47107504/8387076) but it doesn't have any good answer.

Comment: Are you running 32-bit Windows?

Comment: And there is a 32-bit specific download of Android Studio for Windows here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: @MichaelDodd I'll check that out. And yes, it's 32-bit windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio uses OpenJDK by default (which is bundled with Android Studio installer). If you're running Windows 32bit please install 32bit Oracle JDK (at least version JDK8).

After installing JDK. In Android Studio goto **File** -> **Project Structure** -> uncheck OpenJDK (jre) path -> and browse to the path where you installed Oracle JDK.

Example Oracle JDK installation path be like

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk_x.x.x\
```

And click OK. Wait for the gradle sync complete.